# What is this [i] in my shell?

Tags: terminal, fish

***FISH SHELL***

This is probably something very obvious but I literally cannot work out what it is. I want to get rid of it.

What is the capital I in square brackets doing?

[image]

Comment: [superuser](http://superuser.com). You might have installed a few custom options

Comment: what is the output of `type fish_prompt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have enabled vi-mode, which triggered the mode indicator.

The "[I]" stands for "insert mode". If you press escape, you'll see it change to an "[N]" for "normal mode". If that doesn't make any sense to you, disable vi-mode again with `set fish_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings` (you can get back to insert mode by pressing "i").

If you wish to disable this indicator, define an empty function called `fish_mode_prompt`.

If you didn't enable this manually, it might have been enabled via some third-party plugin or theme. I know for a fact the "budspencer-theme" for some reason "requires" vi-mode.